# MySQL subquery/complex query question, tracking state changes

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that tracks contact class state changes by date. The question that I am trying to answer is what is the current state of all contacts on a certain date.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `contact_class_state`;
CREATE TABLE `contact_class_state` (
    `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `contact_id` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL, -- the contact
    `contact_class` int unsigned,
    `state_date` date,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX (`contact_id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `contact_class_state` (`contact_id`, `contact_class`, `state_date`) VALUES
(1, 1, '2011-01-01'),
(2, 1, '2011-01-01'),
(3, 1, '2011-01-01'),
(4, 1, '2011-01-01'),
(5, 1, '2011-01-01'),
(1, 2, '2011-02-01'),
(3, 2, '2011-02-01'),
(5, 2, '2011-02-01'),
(1, 1, '2011-02-15'),
(5, 3, '2011-03-01');
```

For example, the following query:

```
SELECT contact_id, contact_class, state_date
FROM contact_class_state
WHERE state_date <= '2011-02-27'
ORDER BY contact_id, state_date DESC
```

returns

```
+------------+---------------+------------+
| contact_id | contact_class | state_date |
+------------+---------------+------------+
|          1 |             1 | 2011-02-15 |
|          1 |             2 | 2011-02-01 |
|          1 |             1 | 2011-01-01 |
|          2 |             1 | 2011-01-01 |
|          3 |             2 | 2011-02-01 |
|          3 |             1 | 2011-01-01 |
|          4 |             1 | 2011-01-01 |
|          5 |             2 | 2011-02-01 |
|          5 |             1 | 2011-01-01 |
+------------+---------------+------------+
```

While this is technically correct, I only need the first (or last if sorted ASC) row for each contact_id as the latest date will always give me current state of the contact, per the below:

```
+------------+---------------+------------+
| contact_id | contact_class | state_date |
+------------+---------------+------------+
|          1 |             1 | 2011-02-15 |
|          2 |             1 | 2011-01-01 |
|          3 |             2 | 2011-02-01 |
|          4 |             1 | 2011-01-01 |
|          5 |             2 | 2011-02-01 |
+------------+---------------+------------+
```

I am pretty sure a sub or a complex query would do the trick but I am having a mental block with the SQL. I am also open to other approaches to solve this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your query is in fact what you want (except then grouped by contact_id), then do exactly that.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT contact_id, contact_class, state_date
FROM contact_class_state
WHERE state_date <= '2011-02-27'
ORDER BY contact_id, state_date DESC) table1
GROUP BY contact_id
```

This is tested and works perfect.

Comment: Maybe i'm missing something, but is there a reason you need the sub-select?

Comment: Thanks! I was fooling around with the GROUP BY without using the subquery. It makes sense now. I am also open to completely different approaches if anyone has suggestions.

Comment: @Dave You need to first get the results desired, and then group by the contact to get the first result set for each contact.  Your solution below does not return the proper contact_class.